# No route found using Aura Router for PHP

Tags: php, localhost, url-routing

The app uses Aura Router for routing. Accesing the index.php of the web app simply returns a "Route not found" error message.

Here's the (seemingly) relevant code:

```
$path = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);

$route = $router->match($path, $_SERVER);

if (empty($route)) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    echo 'Route not found';
exit;
     }
```

I'm running this locally, using wampserver. The path to where I have the app is localhost/websites

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

The manual may help you out here:  https://github.com/auraphp/Aura.Router#handling-failure-to-match

(I'm the lead on Aura.)

Answer (score 0):

You should check the value of `$path` and verify it's the correct. I had the same issue and I realized I was using a wrong data.

Let's say that your website is on: `example.com/path/sub/` and you want to route all will be next to `sub/`. Your `$path` should be `/` for to use `$router` like this: `$router->add("home", "/")`.

If `$path = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"], PHP_URL_PATH);` then this value will be `/path/sub/` so your router will have to point to the route: `$router->add("home", "/path/sub/")`.

You also should be very careful with end `/` because can or not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the walk-through in the file "getting-started.md".

It helped me.

The code snippet below allows the route "/blog/{id}" which is similar to the following URL on localhost:  http://localhost/blog/42

```
$routerContainer = new RouterContainer();
$map = $routerContainer->getMap();
$map->get('blog.read', '/blog/{id}', function ($request, $response) {
    $id = (int) $request->getAttribute('id');
    echo "You asked for blog entry {$id}.<br/>";        
    httperror(200);
});     
//
// ... Create more routes here ...
//
$request = Zend\Diactoros\ServerRequestFactory::fromGlobals(
    $_SERVER, $_GET, $_POST, $_COOKIE, $_FILES
);
$matcher = $routerContainer->getMatcher();
$route = $matcher->match($request);
if (!$route) {
    $failedRoute = $matcher->getFailedRoute();  
    switch ($failedRoute->failedRule) {
        case 'Aura\Router\Rule\Allows':
            httperror(405);
            break;
        case 'Aura\Router\Rule\Accepts':
            httperror(406);
            break;
        default:
            httperror(404);
            break;
    }
    die();
} 
foreach ($route->attributes as $key => $val) {
    $request = $request->withAttribute($key, $val);
}
$response = new \Zend\Diactoros\Response;
$callable = $route->handler;
$response = $callable($request,$response);
```